# How can i make the loops and create it dynamically?

Tags: javascript, loops

How to correct the javascript code to create li dynamically
to make loops?

I use this code, how to do it?

Because in this code I have to repeat for each section

```
    let content = document.createElement('span');
    let liststart = document.createElement('span');

    let listelement1 = document.createElement('li');
    let listelement2 = document.createElement('li');
    let listelement3 = document.createElement('li');
    let listelement4 = document.createElement('li');

    listelement1.innerHTML = "section 1";
    listelement2.innerHTML = "section 2";
    listelement3.innerHTML = "section 3";
    listelement4.innerHTML = "section 4";

    let section1 = document.getElementById("section1");
    let section2 = document.getElementById("section2");
    let section3 = document.getElementById("section3");
    let section4 = document.getElementById("section4");

    listelement1.addEventListener("click", function() {
      section1.scrollIntoView(true);
      section1.classList.add("my-active");
      section2.classList.remove("my-active");
      section3.classList.remove("my-active");
      section4.classList.remove("my-active");
    });

    listelement2.addEventListener("click", function() {
      section2.scrollIntoView(true);
      section1.classList.remove("my-active");
      section2.classList.add("my-active");
      section3.classList.remove("my-active");
      section4.classList.remove("my-active");
    });

    listelement3.addEventListener("click", function() {
      section3.scrollIntoView(true);
      section1.classList.remove("my-active");
      section2.classList.remove("my-active");
      section3.classList.add("my-active");
      section4.classList.remove("my-active");
    });

    listelement4.addEventListener("click", function() {
      section4.scrollIntoView(true);
      section1.classList.remove("my-active");
      section2.classList.remove("my-active");
      section3.classList.remove("my-active");
      section4.classList.add("my-active");
    });

    liststart.appendChild(listelement1);
    liststart.appendChild(listelement2);
    liststart.appendChild(listelement3);
    liststart.appendChild(listelement4);

    content.appendChild(liststart);

    let navbar__list = document.querySelector('#navbar__list');
    navbar__list.append(content);

    let tabs = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

    for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
      tabs[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

        let current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
        current[0].className = current[0].className.replace("active");
        this.className += "active";
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will work as an example for you:

```js
let content = document.createElement('span');

let liststart = document.createElement('span');

var sections = [];

for(let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
  const listElement = document.createElement('li');
  listElement.innerText = `Section ${i}`
  const section = document.getElementById(`section${i}`)
  sections.push(section)
  listElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
    section.scrollIntoView(true)
    sections.forEach(el => el.classList.remove("my-active"))
    section.classList.add("my-active")
  })
  liststart.appendChild(listElement)
}

content.appendChild(liststart);

let navbar__list = document.querySelector('#navbar__list');
navbar__list.append(content);

let tabs = document.getElementsByTagName("li");


for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
  tabs[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    let current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace("active");
    this.className += "active";
  });
}
```

---

If I was to do this myself, knowing there were an "unknown" number of sections, I would use JavaScript code that used every section whose id started with "secton":

```js
let content = document.createElement('span');
let liststart = document.createElement('span');
// this line puts all elements that have an id starting with 'section' into an array
var sections = [...document.querySelectorAll('[id^=section]')] 

sections.forEach(section => {
  const listElement = document.createElement('li');
  listelement.innerText = `Section ${i}`
  listElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
    section.scrollIntoView(true)
    sections.forEach(el => el.classList.remove("my-active"))
    section.classList.add("my-active")
  })
  liststart.appendChild(listElement)
})

content.appendChild(liststart);

let navbar__list = document.querySelector('#navbar__list');
navbar__list.append(content);

let tabs = document.getElementsByTagName("li");


for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
  tabs[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    let current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace("active");
    this.className += "active";
  });
}
```

This solution is quite similar, but to me is a bit more readable.

Comment: thank you for your help, but the navbar disappeared on the browser chrome and i got error on console , Uncaught ReferenceError: listelement is not defined
    at app.js:10
(anonymous) @ app.js:10

Comment: What is the error in the console? You might not want to copy my code directly, but try and read it and apply the principles in your own code.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: listelement is not defined at app.js:10 (anonymous) @ app.js:10

Comment: i tried modifying not just a copy, the code but still not working!

Comment: Are you using the variable `listElement` somewhere outside the loop? It's only defined inside the loop. Also, note that the `E` in `listElement` is capitalized. I see that I made an error on that. Fixed it now.

Comment: i think i have an issue with the array.

Comment: // this line puts all elements that have an id starting with 'section' into an array
var sections = [...document.querySelectorAll('[id^=section]')]

Comment: var section = ["section1", "section2", "section3", "section4"];

Comment: I'm not sure if you solved your problem, Firas, but I'm not sure if I can help further if you don't supply more specific infomration. The error-message you posted previously was helpful, but I suspect you have another issue now.

Comment: now i need to add an active class to a section and also the corresponding link when it is in window view.
Also remove the active class from the section and link when it is no longer in view.

Comment: That sounds like a new issue that you should create a new question for, or google on its own :) If my answer helped you along the way, or was "correct", please mark it as the accepted answer. Good luck Firas!

Comment: this is the new question ,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66867406/how-to-add-an-active-class-to-a-section-when-it-is-in-window-view

Comment: [What to do when someone answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)